# Batch Command, calling File within command

Tags: batch-file

What am I missing?

```
@echo off
rem - processfiles.bat - Processes all text files in the "source" folder:
rem - Runs %executable% with each text file as parameter
rem - Move the text file to the target folder after processing

set SourceFolder=C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Yield_Files
set TargetFolder=C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\YieldCleanFiles
set fin=default.set


if not exist "%TargetFolder%" md "%TargetFolder%"

echo Processing text files in %SourceFolder%:

for %%f in (%SourceFolder%\*.txt) do call "C:\Program Files\Yield_Editor\yieldeditor.exe/csvin="(%SourceFolder%\*.txt)"/auto="y"/hide/fin=%fin%"%%f

pause
```

I have to have the file name I am working on each time I call the .exe

when ran it says it cannot find the file specified, but I am not sure which one it is talking about.

Comment: Remove the **call** from the for loop.  Just use the name of the executable

Comment: Remove the `@echo off`, start your batch file in the command prompt rather than just double-clicking, and observe the outputs...

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
for %%f in (%SourceFolder%\*.txt) do call "C:\Program Files\Yield_Editor\yieldeditor.exe/csvin="(%SourceFolder%\*.txt)"/auto="y"/hide/fin=%fin%"%%f
```

must be written most likely

```
for %%f in ("%SourceFolder%\*.txt") do "C:\Program Files\Yield_Editor\yieldeditor.exe" /csvin="%SourceFolder%\*.txt" /auto=y /hide /fin=%fin% "%%~f"
```

or

```
for %%f in ("%SourceFolder%\*.txt") do "%ProgramFiles%\Yield_Editor\yieldeditor.exe" "/csvin=%SourceFolder%\*.txt" /auto=y /hide /fin=%fin% "%%~f"
```

which means your executable must be run with syntax

```
"Path to Application\Application.exe" "/First Option" /Option2 /Option3 /Option4 "File Name As Fifth Parameter"
```

File name of application with file extension and path must be in quotes if there is at least 1 space or another character with a special meaning which are output in a command prompt window on last help page displayed when running in command prompt window `cmd /?`. This is argument 0 for the application.

The first parameter/option is argument 1 for the application. It must be in quotes if the parameter string contains a space or another special character. Options not containing a space must not be quoted, but can be nevertheless also quoted.

Some applications support quoting inside an option with a variable string. An example for such a syntax would be `/csvin="%SourceFolder%\*.txt"`.

Read the help/documentation of the application for details on using it from command line. Most Windows console applications can be executed from within a command prompt window with just `/?` as parameter for printing command line help to console.

It can be seen here why argument strings with spaces must be enclosed in quotes. The space is the separator for the arguments.